# Convert to numeric from factor with thousand and decimal separators in R

Tags: r

I have imported data to R with decimal and thousands separators. Numbers looks like 1.234,56 and are imported as facors. How can I convert it to numeric?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` twice, first to get rid of the thousand separator "." and then to replace the decimal separator `,` with a `.`. Finally we use `as.numeric` on the string. Since the original string is a factor we **have** to use `as.character` first!

```
weird_factor_number <- factor("1.234,56")
as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("[^0-9,]", "", as.character(weird_factor_number ))))
```

This returns:

```
[1] 1234.56
```